# How to convert dp to float in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, screen, display

I want to get middle of the users screen while in activity and I tried to convert DisplayMetrics to Float.
The error says "Unresolved reference."
How do I get Float from DisplayPixels?
Heres my code:

```
val dpFloat = dp.toFloat()
```

I wanted to get Float from DisplayMetrics.

Comment: `dp = pixels / density;`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your question.

What you need is the following:

```
val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
val dpToFloat = (sizeInDp * scale)
```

To put it more clearly, you can simplify this into this Kotlin extension function:

```
fun Float.dpToFloat(): Float {
    val scale = resources.displayMetrics.density
    return (this * scale)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to extend `Dp` then it could just be called `toFloat()`?

Answer (score 0):

I have these extension functions and use them a lot. I wish it helps you.

```
import android.content.res.Resources
import kotlin.math.ceil

val Int.dpf: Float
    get() {
        return dp.toFloat()
    }


val Float.dpf: Float
    get() {
        return dp.toFloat()
    }

val Int.dp: Int
    get() {
        return if (this == 0) {
            0
        } else ceil((Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density * this).toDouble()).toInt()
    }

val Float.dp: Int
    get() {
        return if (this == 0f) {
            0
        } else ceil((Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density * this).toDouble()).toInt()
    }
```

Usage examples:

```
10.dp       // Int   -> Int
10.dpf      // Int   -> Float
(10.5f).dp  // Float -> Int
(10.5f).dpf // Float -> Float
```